# Inverse kinematics bone doesn't stick to its source

Tags: rigging, armature

When I grab the `footIK.L` bone in the below image, everything seems to be working except for movement of the `footIK.L` bone. In tutorials, duplicated bone (`footIK.L`) stciks to its source bone (`foot.L`) and when grabbed they move together.

How can I stick the `footIK.L` bone to the `foot.L` bone?

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PR8wODbC6tRUVpRVVMYi1fVTQ/view?usp=sharing)

[image: ik_problem]

Comment: I downloaded the file. I'm not sure about how you wish to move this ik bone. Can I see the tutorial you are following?

Comment: @m.ardito https://youtu.be/VVHKBSknFhA?t=4m15s

Comment: mmm I can't fully understand but for sure in the video (I just saw a few minutes) I see two different things: 1) he's using xyz eulers, 2) he says he duplucated the foot.L boen to Foot.IK.L so then ht IK bone "is still parented" but your IK bone is not parented to the upper bone "bone". 
Then, his IK chain has also one more bone above... I'l try later...

Comment: @m.ardito Thaks for your interest. He brokes the parent relation at 1:50. Also, I have omitted the upper (fourth) bone for clarity. By the way, if we click to the red/green/blue circles and tweak, footIK.L keeps sticked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that

1. your IK could be too short. The video you are following use another bone above that with the IK constraint.
2. this does not allow you to replicate what he's doing in the video: he grabs the IK target but he doesn't moves it too far from the chain.

To find out, try to

1. remove the IK constraint from the bone "bone"
2. select the bone "bone", and subdivide it (press "w" > subdvide)
3. now you have 2 bones above the IK target bone
4. select the new bone, that is now directly attached to the IK target (it should be named "bone.001"
5. reapply the same IK constraint to the IK target as it was before
6. now grab the IK target and move it around: it stays with the constrained bone.
7. however, if you move the IK target too far, the constrained bone can't "stay" with it and they separate until the IK target is too far...

[image]